# Pyglet textures are messed up

Tags: python, opengl, 3d, textures, pyglet

I have been following an Pyglet OpenGL tutorial on Youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hqg4qePJV2U) and I followed it around a year or two ago. It worked quite well and I managed to make a Minecraft clone which included simple physics. Now, I've lost the code and I tried to recreate it. I followed the video, but it took too long so I just downloaded it from the link. Then, the only thing I replaced was the `tex = pyglet.image.load(file).texture`, because apparently I should use `tex = pyglet.image.load(file).get_texture()`. Then, when I ran it, the cube looked very distorted and the textures were all in the wrong place. Here are links to the cube pictures:

[image]

[image]

The code is here:

```py
from pyglet.gl import *
from pyglet.window import key
import math


class Model:

    def get_tex(self,file):
        tex = pyglet.image.load(file).get_texture()
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST)
        return pyglet.graphics.TextureGroup(tex)

    def __init__(self):

        self.top = self.get_tex('grass_top.png')
        self.side = self.get_tex('grass_side.png')
        self.bottom = self.get_tex('dirt.png')

        self.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

        tex_coords = ('t2f',(0,0, 1,0, 1,1, 0,1, ))

        x,y,z = -1,-1,-1
        X,Y,Z = x+2,y+2,z+2

        self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.side, ('v3f',(x,y,z, x,y,Z, x,Y,Z, x,Y,z)), tex_coords)
        self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.side, ('v3f',(X,y,Z, X,y,z, X,Y,z, X,Y,Z)), tex_coords)
        self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.bottom, ('v3f',(x,y,z, X,y,z, X,y,Z, x,y,Z)), tex_coords)
        self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.top, ('v3f',(x,Y,Z, X,Y,Z, X,Y,z, x,Y,z)), tex_coords)
        self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.side, ('v3f',(X,y,z, x,y,z, x,Y,z, X,Y,z)), tex_coords)
        self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.side, ('v3f',(x,y,Z, X,y,Z, X,Y,Z, x,Y,Z)), tex_coords)

    def draw(self):
        self.batch.draw()



class Player:
    def __init__(self,pos=(0,0,0),rot=(0,0)):
        self.pos = list(pos)
        self.rot = list(rot)

    def mouse_motion(self,dx,dy):
        dx/=8; dy/=8; self.rot[0]+=dy; self.rot[1]-=dx
        if self.rot[0]>90: self.rot[0] = 90
        elif self.rot[0]<-90: self.rot[0] = -90

    def update(self,dt,keys):
        s = dt*10
        rotY = -self.rot[1]/180*math.pi
        dx,dz = s*math.sin(rotY),s*math.cos(rotY)
        if keys[key.W]: self.pos[0]+=dx; self.pos[2]-=dz
        if keys[key.S]: self.pos[0]-=dx; self.pos[2]+=dz
        if keys[key.A]: self.pos[0]-=dz; self.pos[2]-=dx
        if keys[key.D]: self.pos[0]+=dz; self.pos[2]+=dx

        if keys[key.SPACE]: self.pos[1]+=s
        if keys[key.LSHIFT]: self.pos[1]-=s


class Window(pyglet.window.Window):

    def push(self,pos,rot): glPushMatrix(); glRotatef(-rot[0],1,0,0); glRotatef(-rot[1],0,1,0); glTranslatef(-pos[0],-pos[1],-pos[2],)
    def Projection(self): glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); glLoadIdentity()
    def Model(self): glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glLoadIdentity()
    def set2d(self): self.Projection(); gluOrtho2D(0,self.width,0,self.height); self.Model()
    def set3d(self): self.Projection(); gluPerspective(90,self.width/self.height,0.05,1000); self.Model()

    def setLock(self,state): self.lock = state; self.set_exclusive_mouse(state)
    lock = False; mouse_lock = property(lambda self:self.lock,setLock)

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.set_minimum_size(300, 200)
        self.keys = key.KeyStateHandler()
        self.push_handlers(self.keys)
        pyglet.clock.schedule(self.update)

        self.model = Model()
        self.player = Player((0,0,5),(0,0))

    def on_mouse_motion(self,x,y,dx,dy):
        if self.mouse_lock: self.player.mouse_motion(dx,dy)

    def on_key_press(self,KEY,MOD):
        if KEY == key.ESCAPE: self.close()
        elif KEY == key.E: self.mouse_lock = not self.mouse_lock

    def update(self,dt):
        self.player.update(dt,self.keys)

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.set3d()
        self.push(self.player.pos,self.player.rot)
        self.model.draw()
        glPopMatrix()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Window(width=854,height=480,caption='Minecraft',resizable=True)
    glClearColor(0.5,0.7,1,1)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    # glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Note: I fiddled with the textures and when I replaced the batch adds with this:

```py
self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.top, ('v3f',(x,y,z, x,y,Z, x,Y,Z, x,Y,z)), tex_coords)
self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.top, ('v3f',(X,y,Z, X,y,z, X,Y,z, X,Y,Z)), tex_coords)
self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.side, ('v3f',(x,y,z, X,y,z, X,y,Z, x,y,Z)), tex_coords)
self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.bottom, ('v3f',(x,Y,Z, X,Y,Z, X,Y,z, x,Y,z)), tex_coords)
self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.top, ('v3f',(X,y,z, x,y,z, x,Y,z, X,Y,z)), tex_coords)
self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.top, ('v3f',(x,y,Z, X,y,Z, X,Y,Z, x,Y,Z)), tex_coords)
```

The cube was textured properly. Any ideas why?

Also, when I only drew one side, it was in the right place but the texture was bending over the face, as if it were two triangles.

Comment: You've to show the code code that specifies the vertex attributes.

Comment: Vertex coordinates, texture coordinates etc. are vertex attributes.

Comment: @RayChen Please add the relevant code in code-blocks in your question. Preferably a minimal working example that we can copy and execute ourselves (as we don't like copying from images or videos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. After testing the exact same code on a newer PC, it worked. Seems like I have an outdated GPU or graphics driver, just like Rabbid76 said.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test):

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Window(width = 400, height = 300, caption = "Minecraft", resizable = True)
    glClearColor(0.5, 0.7, 1, 1)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) # <----
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Note that the cube appears to be screwed up since the front of the cube doesn't cover the back. The depth test ensures that a geometry that has already been drawn is not covered by a new geometry that is behind it.

Comment: I posted the wrong code before and I've edited my question. I do have the depth test enabled but I don't know why it is still messed up.

Comment: @RayChen Sorry, but I cannot reproduce the issue. Possibly your widow doesn't even have a depth buffer. Is the graphics driver up to date?

Comment: I don't know, but I probably can't modify it because I'm using my dad's computer, not my own. I'll check it out on another computer.